# Codeigniter - select e imprimir valores

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boas, estou a tentar imprimir valores numa página de um select que eu fiz num model. Mas dá-me o erro: Undefined variable: login.
Controller:

```
function perfil()
{
    $this->load->model('perfil_model');
    $data['list'] = $this->perfil_model->getAllDisplayable3();
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
}
```

Model: perfil_model

```
function getAllDisplayable3()
 {
    $this->db->select('id_login, nome, username, password, cod_postal, telefone, email, localidade, rua');
    $result = $this->db->get('login');      
    return $result->result();
 }
```

View: perfil_view

```
 <input class="form-control" id="nome" value="<?php echo $login->nome?>" type="text">
```

O que está errado ou em falta? Obrigada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do método `perfil()` você colocou `$data['list']` e na sua `View` chamou `$login`, então mude no método `perfil()` para

```
$data['listPerfil'] = $this->perfil_model->getAllDisplayable3();
```

---

***Código completo:***

```
function perfil()
{
    $this->load->model('perfil_model');
    $data['listPerfil'] = $this->perfil_model->getAllDisplayable3();
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
}
```

***Observação:*** Se for mesmo para exibir uma lista de valores poderia então ser assim:

***Método:***

```
function perfil()
{
    $this->load->model('perfil_model');
    $data['listPerfil'] = $this->perfil_model->getAllDisplayable3();
    $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->load->view('perfil_view',$data);
}
```

***View***

```
<?php foreach($listPerfil as $p): ?>
<input class="form-control" id="nome" value="<?php echo $p->nome;?>" type="text">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

*Só lembrando também que o comando* `result` (do método `getAllDisplayable3()`) *retorna uma* ***lista de objetos***.

***Referencia:*** [Result Arrays](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=result#id1)